# Unable to send a JMS message using WSO2 DSS output event trigger

Tags: triggers, wso2, jms, wso2-data-services-server

I am using WSO2 DSS 3.2.1 and trying to configure an output event trigger with the following event sink URL:

```
jms:/ MyQueueName?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=Content-Type&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://10.11.11.15:61616&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory
```

but unable to make WSO2 DSS work in the way as expected:

```
TID: [0] [DSS] [2014-10-04 05:33:55,576]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: EventingSample.dbs - file:/C:/WSO2DS~1.1/bin/../repository/deployment/server/dataservices/samples/EventingSample.dbs {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}

TID: [0] [DSS] [2014-10-04 05:34:06,371] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/MyQueueName?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=Content-Type&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://10.11.11.15:61616&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory URL. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}

TID: [0] [DSS] [2014-10-04 05:34:06,371] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.ws.internal.notify.WSEventDispatcher} -  Unable to send message {org.wso2.carbon.event.ws.internal.notify.WSEventDispatcher}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the jms:/ MyQueueName?transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty=Content-Type&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://10.11.11.15:61616&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue&transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.fireAndForget(ServiceClient.java:511)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.fireAndForget(ServiceClient.java:488)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.ws.internal.notify.WSEventDispatcher.sendNotification(WSEventDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.ws.internal.notify.WSEventDispatcher.notify(WSEventDispatcher.java:66)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.notify.CarbonNotificationManager.sendNotification(CarbonNotificationManager.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.delivery.Worker.run(Worker.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked/confirmed that nothing is wrong on the Active MQ side, including ip address, port number, and queue name. And `org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender` is also enabled. Appreciate any help on this issue.

By the way, I also took a working JMS endpoint URI already properly tested with WSO2 ESB but still got the same error with WSO2 DSS. It seems to me that something is wrong with WSO2 DSS JMS transport.

Answer (score 0):

Above error was occurring because you have enabled the `org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender` in the `axis2.xml` but not the `axis2-client.xml`. To use jms sender you need to enable the jms transport in `axis2_client.xml`.